# TypeScript: How to type and use function on generic function (higher-order function)?

Tags: typescript, generics, type-inference, higher-order-functions

I have defined a utility function `withUndefined` as follows:

```
function withUndefined<TInput, TFurtherArguments extends any[], TOutput>(
    func: (input: TInput, ...furtherArguments: TFurtherArguments) => TOutput
) {
  function transformedFunc(input: undefined, ...furtherArguments: TFurtherArguments): undefined;
  function transformedFunc(input: TInput, ...furtherArguments: TFurtherArguments): TOutput;
  function transformedFunc(input: TInput | undefined, ...furtherArguments: TFurtherArguments): TOutput | undefined;
  function transformedFunc(input: TInput | undefined, ...furtherArguments: TFurtherArguments): TOutput | undefined {
    if (input === undefined) return undefined;
    return func(input, ...furtherArguments);
  }
  return transformedFunc;
}
```

It is supposed to convert any function `func(input: TInput, ...): TOutput` to a "more robust" function `transformedFunc(input: TInput | undefined, ...): TOutput | undefined`, where the output is `undefined` if and only if the input is also `undefined`. Works great in many cases.

But not if `func` is a generic function. Here, the typing information is lost. For example:

```
function filterOutUndefined<E>(array: (E | undefined)[]): E[] {
  return array.filter((value) => value !== undefined) as E[];
}
const filterOutUndefined_ = withUndefined(filterOutUndefined);

const x = filterOutUndefined(['a', 'b', 'c']); // type of x is string[], as it should be
const y = filterOutUndefined_(['a', 'b', 'c']); // type of y is unknown[]
```

What could I do to retain the generics? Is this even possible with TypeScript, given that it still lacks higher-order types (if that has something to do with the problem)?

Comment: I believe you should overload your higher order function - `withUndefined` also

Comment: Thanks, but I think `withUndefined` has only a single signature because `func` also has only a single signature.